# How to use Include in GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

This is part of my model:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public Subcategory TransactionSubcategory { get; set; }
    public Member OwnerMember { get; set; }
    public int TransactionSubcategoryId { get; set; }
    public int OwnerMemberId { get; set; }
}

public class Subcategory
{
    public Subcategory()
    {
        IsGlobal = false;
        Transactions = new List<Transaction>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Category OwnerCategory { get; set; }
    public List<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
    public bool IsGlobal { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        IsGlobal = false;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Subcategory> Subcategories { get; set; }
    public TransactionType TypeOfTransaction { get; set; }
    public Budget OwnerBudget { get; set; }
    public bool IsGlobal { get; set; }
}

public class Member
{
    public Member()
    {
        Transactions = new List<Transaction>();
    }
    public Budget OwnerBudget { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }
    public List<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}
```

In this method I try to include `TransactionSubcategory.OwnerCategory`

```
    private List<ReportMembers> GetMembersReport(IQueryable<Transaction> transactions)
    {
        var members = transactions
            .Include(t=> t.TransactionSubcategory.OwnerCategory)
            .GroupBy(t => t.OwnerMember, t => t)
            .ToList();
...
     }
```

but it is still null. If I change to

```
        var members = transactions
            .GroupBy(t => t.OwnerMember, t => t)
            .Include(t=> t.Select(t2 => t2.TransactionSubcategory.OwnerCategory))
            .ToList();
```

I am gettin error:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.

Comment: Does `.Include("TransactionSubcategory").Include("TransactionSubcategory.OwnerCategory")` work?

Comment: Do you have that field defined as a foreign key?

Comment: 1) No it doesn't work 2) I didn't add any atributes to model, but i found a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. If i first make `ToList` and later `GroupBy` its works.

```
var members = transactions
            .Include(t => t.TransactionSubcategory.OwnerCategory)
            .Include(t=> t.OwnerMember).ToList()
            .GroupBy(t => t.OwnerMember, t => t)
```

Comment: But this solution is very slow as now the C# runtime is performing the grouping and not the database engine.

Comment: so what is the solution @Stefan?

Answer (score 0):

First: you should include those navigations when selecting from database:

```
from o in context.Transactions.Include("TransactionSubcategory").Include("TransactionSubcategory.OwnerCategory")
...
select o
```

Second: remove Include from here

```
var members = transactions
            .GroupBy(t => t.OwnerMember, t => t)
            .ToList();
```

Third: I believe you want to group by ID and not by class, because grouping by reference type will not give you expected result. All classes with same fields will produce different group, because they have different references.

```
var members = transactions
                .GroupBy(t => t.OwnerMember.Id, t => t)
                .ToList();
```